# Filter for boolean null values in Kendo grid with Multi(true)

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Model has field "BarrelType" which is bool? type.
Depends on the value in the grid user see different values.

```
columns
    .Bound(device => device.BarrelType)
    .ClientTemplate(
    "# if (BarrelType == null) { #" +
            "Any" +
    "# } else if (BarrelType == true) { #" +
        "Opened" +
    "# } else { #" +
        "Closed" +
    "# } #"
    )
    .Filterable(filter => filter.Multi(true))
    .Width(130);
```

I want to have filter with multiple selection that works with "null" value.
To get multiple selection filter I'm using ForeignKey:

```
    .ForeignKey("BarrelType", new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Any", Value = null },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Closed", Value = bool.FalseString },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Opened", Value = bool.TrueString },
    }, "Value", "Text"))
```

Hovewer when I select "Any" option I'm getting wrong results (rows with "false" values)
Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: You might be able to do something in jquery using IsEmpty. See [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-filter.operator)

Comment: Is this a solution for multiple items choise?